# Turn chrome.tabcapture.capture into an audio file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I"m trying to use the chrome API https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture. 
How do I get a audio file out of it. For example, if I'm watching youtube and want to export whatever song I'm doing into an audio file MP3, wav, etc. I know there are some chrome extensions out there that does this but I want to know if there is an API.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [desktopCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) API with DesktopCaptureSourceType "audio"

Saving the stream may be more challenging. You could create a Web Audio API Audio context and call [decodeAudioData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/decodeAudioData)() to get raw PCM data (e.g. .wav file). MP3 encoding you might be able to find some kind of [Emscripten module](https://github.com/higuma/mp3-lame-encoder-js) for.

Alternatively, it looks like there is a media recorder API ([demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/msr/audio-recorder.html)) I'm not sure if this is stable in many browsers yet, but I just tried in Chrome and it seemed to work.

Comment: i noticed that desktopCapture has chooseDesktopMedia and you get a streamId from it as parameter of the callback. This wasn't so obvious to me but how do you get a .wav file from this?

Comment: url=window.URL.createObjectURL(streamid), then create an <audio> with src set to that URL. converting WAV you'd use web audio API.

Comment: Or MediaRecorder: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder