# Chrome's tabcapture api not recording all audio on tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I'm working on an application where an extension will record a tab and save it. The tab recording part worked pretty easily but for some reason the tab record didn't save the remote audio I got from webrtc (it did record the other noises the tab was making).

Here is how I start the tab recording:

```js
    chrome.tabCapture.capture({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
      if (!stream) {
        console.error('Couldn\'t obtain stream.');
      }

      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'video/webm'});
      mediaRecorder.start();
      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
        if (event.data.size > 0) {
          recordedChuncks.push(event.data);
        }
      }
    });
```

The audio item that is missing in the recording is set up as follows:

```html
    <audio
      id="remoteAudio"
      ref={el => {
        this._remoteAudio = el;
      }}
      autoPlay
      playsInline
    />
```

And this audio elemet is given it's source from a remote video stream (`this._remoteAudio.srcObject = remoteMediaStream`).

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or maybe this isn't currently possible.

Comment: I don't know the chrome:// side of the Force, but that sounds like a bug indeed. *(no pun intended)*. Does this happen only with remote streams or also with a local stream (either from gUM, WebAudioAPI or even an other MediaElement's `captureStream`)?

Answer (score 1):

There's a blog post written by Google Chrome Devs in [this post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder) on how to do this using *MediaStream Recording API*:

**Record Audio and Video with MediaRecorder**

> The *MediaRecorder API* enables you to record audio and video from a
>   web app. It's available now in Firefox and in Chrome for Android and
>   desktop. • Audio recording work in Firefox and in Chrome 49 and above;
>   Chrome 47 and 48 only support video recording.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46020000) might also provide additional insight.